ParcelJs window.hasMobileFirstExtension = true;
I have a problem with ParcelJS. A "window.hasMobileFirstExtension = true;" is always included in the head section of the index.html file. How can I prevent this?
I would be grateful for an answer.
I have searched for an error message in the browser (console). But no error message is displayed. This error message occurred after executing
"npx parcel build src/index.html".
